# How to install Linux in a flash drive

Tags: linux, windows, multi-boot

I want to install Linux on my flash drive so that it functions like a plug and play PC. For this I have selected lubuntu 18.04 LTS. But I don't want it to ask which operating system to boot. If the flash drive is inserted, it should directly boot from that, otherwise it should boot normally from the hard drive in which Windows 10 is installed. How can this be acheived?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You need to configure the bios of the target computer to try to boot first from USB devices.**

1. Right after you press the power on button, there should be a prompt
   on screen ( F2 or DEL )
2. You need to navigate the menus to the boot options. Give priority to
   USB, disable secure boot. *You might also need to switch to legacy boot mode.*
3. Save the settings and apply (Probably F10)

It should now boot from the pen drive if it is connected.